# Testing static classes with PHPUnit

Tags: php, class, static, phpunit

I've got a set of classes I'm trying to test. Class A depends on Class X. Class X contains functions which do random things and things with databases. I've created a mock version of Class X  which returns exactly what I want it to in order to test Class A without dependencies.

So, my question is, how do I now test Class X as I've already included the mock version, which has the same name and filename. I get the "Cannot redeclare Class X" error.

I don't think I can use stubs as there's no way to pass the stubbed object into my class under test. The class under test (Class A) will ask for an instance of a static class (ClassA::getInstance();).

Is this going to be something to do with test suites or test cases as I can't un-include a the file which contains the mock version of Class X.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't uninclude files/classes in PHP, so the classes will either need to use different names or you will need to namespace them.  As for using a stub class, two approaches you could use are. Use an instance/class variable that contains dependancies, so you can swap them out.  Like

```
self::$_classes['classA']::methodCall();
$this->_classes['classA']::methodCall();
```

This will let you change the class dependancies at runtime if you really need statics. The other approach is to not use static classes and use a [dependancy injection container](http://components.symfony-project.org/dependency-injection/) like one found in symfony components. An injection container would let you inject mocks as needed as well.

Answer (score 0):

> > there's no way to pass the stubbed object into my class under test.

This means that your Class A strongly references Class X ? Personally I'd recommend to rename your Class X mockup to a *real* mockup (e.g. `X_MockUp`) put it in a test folder hierarchy and then pass it to the Class A that you want to test. It might be not possible at the moment, but then change your architecture! It will be more flexible and *testable-friendly*.

You get this error as you have the same class name in two files you are forced to differentiate them.